# Homology groups of $(S^2 \times S^1) \setminus B$, where $B$ is a small open ball

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M = (S^2 \times S^1) \setminus B$, where $B$ is a small open ball in $S^2 \times S^1$.

**First question**: How do we compute the absolute and relative homology groups of $M$ (with integer coefficients)? I tried to use Mayer-Vietoris without success..

**Second question**: can we compute the homomorphism $\varphi : H_2(M) \to H_2(M, \partial M)$ arising in the long exact sequence of the pair $(M, \partial M)$?

What I did: I know $H_3(M, \partial M) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_0(M) = \mathbb{Z}$. Now let $B' \subset B$ be a small closed ball, let $U = (S^2 \times S^1)\setminus B'$ and $V = B$. Then $U \cup V = S^2 \times S^1$, $U \cong M$, $V$ is contractible and $U \cap V \cong S^2$. So, Mayer-Vietoris sequence gives us

$$\cdots \to H_3(S^2 \times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{f}{\to} H_2(S^2) \stackrel{g}{\to} H_2(U) \stackrel{h}{\to} H_2(S^2 \times S^1) \to 0$$

By Kunneth Theorem, we have $H_2(S^2 \times S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$, so we get the following sequence:

$$\cdots \to H_3(S^2 \times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{f}{\to} H_2(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{g}{\to} H_2(M) \stackrel{h}{\to} H_2(S^2 \times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

The only thing I know now is that $h$ is surjective and that $H_2(M) \cong \mathbb{Z} / \ker (h) \cong \mathbb{Z} / \operatorname{im}(g)$. How to continue?

Comment: Almost the same question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844370/analyzing-the-homomorphisms-in-the-long-exact-sequence-of-a-manifold-pair