# Analyzing the homomorphisms in the long exact sequence of a manifold pair

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M = (S^2 \times S^1) \setminus B$, where $B$ is a "small" open ball in $S^2 \times S^1$.
We have the following exact sequence in homology with integer coefficients (arising from the long exact sequence of the pair $(M, \partial M)$):

$$\cdots \to H_3(M, \partial M) \stackrel{f}{\to} H_2(\partial M) \stackrel{g}{\to} H_2(M) \stackrel{h}{\to} H_2(M, \partial M) \to 0$$

I know that $H_3(M ,\partial M) \cong H_2(\partial M) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Can we compute the groups $H_2(M)$, $H_2(M, \partial M)$ and the homomorphisms $f,g,h$?

Comment: $$H_2(M;\Bbb Z)\simeq H^1(M,\partial M;\Bbb Z)$$$$\simeq \text{Hom}\big(H_1(M,\partial M),\Bbb Z\big)\oplus \text{Ext}\big(H_0(M,\partial M),\Bbb Z\big)$$$$\simeq \text{Hom}\big(H_1(M,\partial M),\Bbb Z\big)\simeq \text{Hom}(\Bbb Z^k\oplus\text{finite group},\Bbb Z)\simeq \Bbb Z^k$$ for some $k\geq 0$.

Comment: Similarly for $H_2(M,\partial M;\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Now, $0=H_1(\Bbb S^2)=H_1(\partial M)\to H_1(M)\to  H_1(M,\partial M)\to H_0(\partial M)\to H_0(M)$. Since, both $\partial M$ and $M$ are connected and $H_0(\partial M)\to H_0(M)$ is inclusion induced we can say $H_0(\partial M)\to H_0(M)$ is an isomorphism. Hence, $H_1(M,\partial M)\simeq H_1(M)\simeq \pi_1(M)\simeq \pi_1(\Bbb S^2\times \Bbb S^1)=\Bbb Z$ by Van Kampen theorem, since taking a larger ball $B'$ containing $B$ we have $B'\cap B=3$-dimensional annulus.

Comment: @MathLover  how to compute $H_2(M, \partial M)$?

Comment: Same technique as in the first comment. Note that $H_2(M,\partial M;\Bbb Z)\simeq H^1(M;\Bbb Z)$.